# Can't download from repositories

Tags: apt, updates

Whatever I try running `apt update` in the terminal it doesn't work and I just get this message.

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83,2 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/gtk3/ubuntu bionic Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:5 http://ba.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
  Could not connect to ba.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (80.65.85.94), connection timed out
Err:6 http://ba.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not connect to ba.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (80.65.85.94), connection timed out
```

Can someone help me out with this one? I'm a new user so I don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: check in `software and update` may be you are having invalid sources.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. I've it changed to download from the main server and now it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ba.archive.ubuntu.com` is down right now for some reason and hence `apt-get update` is unable to fetch the package list from there. Try switching to the main repository for now by either changing your mirror in Software and Updates or running the following command:

```
sudo sed -i s/ba.archive/archive/g /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo apt-get update
```

This replaces all instances of `ba.archive` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` so that apt uses the main archive (http://archive.ubuntu.com) to update from